# Cannot assign requested address for Django-Docker project

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm building my first project with Docker. I've created a simple `Hello World` with Django and PostgreSQL. Below the structure of the project without and with Docker:

```
No Docker      With Docker
PostgreSQL --> PostgreSQL
Django     --> Container(Django)
```

Therefore PostgreSQL will not use Docker; in development PostgreSQL runs in localhost and in production will be runs in a dedicated server.

When I start Django without Docker I can see the `Hello World` page, but when I run it inside a container I see this error:

> Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 0):

your host machine using the port 5432 , first `stop the postgress service on your host machine` .. and then run container..

if your postgress is on host machine then you `need to use Host Network` instaed of deafault bridge network

Use `--network="host"` in your docker run command, then 127.0.0.1 in your docker container will point to your docker host.

OR

if your docker version is > v20.10 then
add `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to your Docker command to enable this feature.

Comment: If I stop Postgres how I can use it? Postgres DB isn't in a container.